# Working with large integers in Python using GPU

Tags: python, numpy, integer, gpu, biginteger

I implemented a small python program that should find solutions [x,y] which satisfy the equation `y^2=x^6-4x^2+4` (this is just an example) . I would like to investigate various curves later using this Python based approach. But I am missing some knowledge on Python's large integer data types for such tasks. To accelerate its runtime I am using GPU. The code looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
import sys

@jit('void(uint64)')
def findIntegerSolutions(limit: np.uint64):
    for x in np.arange(0, limit, dtype=np.uint64):
        y = np.uint64(x**6-4*x**2+4)
        sqr = np.uint64(np.sqrt(y))
        if np.uint64(sqr*sqr) == y:
            print([x,sqr,y])
                                
def main() -> int:
    limit = 100000000
    findIntegerSolutions(limit)
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

It works fast and fine. Correctly, it provides the solutions `x=0,y=2` and `x=1,y=1`:

```
[0, 2, 4]
[1, 1, 1]
```

Unfortunatelly it also yields the values `x=65536,y=4294967294` and `x=83913453,y=824417755` which both are not solutions:

```
[65536, 4294967294, 18446744056529682436]
[83913453, 824417755, 679664634759240025]
```

I tried many combinations such as using "normal" int types (in the hope Pythan scales their size as needed) and I am keeping to get wrong results. It would be great if anyone could help me to get on the right track in dealing with large numbers.

***Additional Note:***

This short Mathematica snippet does not provide these "false solutions":

```
F[x_] := x^6 - 4 x^2 + 4;
sQ[n_] := FractionalPart@Sqrt[n + 0``1] == 0;
For[i = 0, i < 100000000000, 
 i++, {x = i; y = F[x]; 
  If[sQ[y] == True, Print[{x, Sqrt[y]}], Continue]}]
```

But it runs slower, takes longer, and it would be fantastic if we could get Python doing the job too.

Comment: You're trying to use a 64-bit int to hold something that looks like x^6 for integer x. Unless x is less than about 2^(64/6) ~ 1625 your calculation will overflow.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. Do you have an idea how to ammend the code in order to make it capable of handling larger integers. As I know, a type uint128 does not exist. There hopefully exist some other types doing the trick.

Comment: First off, the python code checks ints up to 100000000. Your Mathematica code checks ints up to 100000000000. You describe this as slower, but actually I don't think it would finish is less than a year.

Comment: Perhaps you can first find integer points on the elliptic curve *y^2 = x^3 - 4x-4*. Any solution `(y,x)` in which `x` is a perfect square yields a solution for your original problem.

Comment: What's your real goal here? You'd probably do better to look into the mathematics rather than trying to do brute-force searches.  You're looking for integer-valued points on the elliptic curve `y^2=x^3-4x+4` for which `x` is a square number. Integer-valued points on rational elliptic curves are a very well studied topic. There are even databases of elliptic curves with small coefficients that list all integer-valued points. See https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/88/a/1, for example, which confirms that `(±1, ±1)` and `(0, ±2)` are the only integer-valued solutions to your equation.

Comment: You can use tricks like a wheel algorithm or sieving to eliminate values of x which cannot be squares mod p for small values of p.

Comment: Thank you for these hints. My goal is to enable that Python Code handling big integer. Later I will investigate different curves as well. I am missing some know-how of Python Data types here.

Comment: Okay: what do the different curves look like? It's difficult for us to extrapolate from just one example. Writing an algorithm to find solutions to general Diophantine equations is impossible - for more, search for "Hilbert's 10th problem". Are your curves all of a particular form?

Comment: Correctly - you are right. The curves will look like elliptic curves, where I will check whether y is a square. It would be great if l can reuse this approach for other diophantine equations. But indeed it would be not possible. As a first step, it would be very helpful to understand first which data type is the correct one to deal with large integers in the given snippet.

Comment: "which data type is the correct one to deal with large integers" <- I think you have two choices: either use the Python `int` type, or if you need extra speed for large integers, try something like `gmpy2` (a wrapper around GMP). Neither of those is likely to be well fitted to GPU-based computations, though. NumPy integer types won't work well here because they're fixed-precision and affected by overflow, as you already discovered.

Comment: Great, thank you. I will try `int` and `gmpy2`. Let's see what performs better.